# MySQL server won't connect to PythonAnywhere Django website

Tags: python, mysql, django, pythonanywhere

Despite all of my efforts, I consistently get this message in the error logs when I try to open my site:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user '<myusername>'@'10.0.0.116' (using password: YES)").
```

My database connection code in Django is this:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<myusername>$<mydatabasename>',
        'USER': '<myusername>',
        'PASSWORD': password, #This links to a password variable that was * imported in from another file
        'HOST': '<myusername>.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
    }
}
```

I have attempted to change the 'PORT' numerous times. It hasn't worked with a default '3306' port, an empty '' port, or in the current form with excluding the 'PORT' altogether.

I have also included the password in the file natively, rather than importing it, but that also changed nothing.

I'm very confused here as everything I've seen online appears to state that what I'm doing is correct, but it is still not working.

Comment: It may or may not be obvious, but did you replace `<myusername>$<mydatabasename>` with your actual username and actual databasename?.

Comment: yeah, just did that on this post for privacy reasons.

Comment: Well Access Denied for username and pw means one of the two or both are incorrect.  What about using a good MySQL browsing software like MySQL Workbench?  Try to connect using it, and if you get the same error, you know its the credentials most likely.

Comment: So, next question is are you sure the user has permission - for example, logging into the MySQL console with this user: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingMySQL/

Comment: Just realized my idiotic mistake - when changing my db password on pythonanywhere to the one I used in the code, it didn't actually change. Apparently pythonanywhere only accepts passwords shorter than 32 characters, so after I made the password shorter, it worked. Thank you for the help